# solving templates conflicts between joomla sites that use the same db

Tags: php, templates, joomla, joomla-extensions

I've got a desktop joomla site which uses the database called 'mydatabase'. However, I've created another site for mobile version in a folder in the same host. Then:

www.mysite.com is my desktop webpage.
www.mysite.com/mobile is my mobile webpage.

Both sites, mobile and desktop, are single and independent joomla instalaltions, but they use the same  db.

Then when I try to configure the default template to render my contents, I`ve got to choose between mobile contents or desktop contents, but not the two.

How can I render my both templates, so both sites work and live together?

Comment: Since the template is being called from the database and you have the templates in the two separate instances I think you need to call them the same thing and make the configuration options  basically have two fieldsets, one for the mobile and one for the other.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you said but I can't figure it out...XD, I just only can set one template of my site as default one, but I need to "activate" both templates so mobile and desktop sites can work well. Could you explain what you said in a better way, maybe step by step or something... do you mean I have to alter the database?

Comment: Ok maybe I'm also not understanding what you said, you said  " I've created another site for mobile version in a folder in the same host"  Do you mean you have a complete copy of the files and folder structure including the templates folder?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla stores most of its configuration options in the database, thus your question requires some coding to handle it.  But let me get one step back.

**1. The Joomla approach**

Joomla allows you to define which pages show which menus.  You could have a simple Joomla installation with SEF turned on, where the main menu is as it is currently in the root.

Then all you need in order to have a /mobile page with a different layout is

1. Create a new menu (not menu item, menu type) and name it SEF or Hidden; this will not be published anywhere.
2. Create a menu item with alias "mobile" in that menu.

This ensures your users will be able to surf to the page /mobile and access that menu item.

Now create a menu for the mobile part of your site, add menu items and choose the default template for each, and create a module to display it.  Assign it to "Show only on the selected pages" and choose the /mobile page you just created and any others contained within the menu.

Then go back to the main menu module, and configure it to "Show on all pages except", and make the same pages selection.

Now you will have two menus, one for the desktop and the other for the mobile. Aside for the template assignment, they will be identical.

**2. Third party extensions**

There are third party plugins which allow you to define a different template based on several parameters: country, useragent, screen size etc.

In addition to what you find on the JED, many templates (mostly commercial ones) have a feature to define a custom layout for mobile users.

Whether you handle this with a plugin or with a template is a matter of personal choice; either will work very effectively and be more appropriate than the Joomla answer I outlined above as they will help you prevent duplication. Duplication in content or menu items is costly as maintenance and testing will be harder.

Comment: I understand your answer... I will try your solution, but I have a doubt: what happen if your mobile version is a complete joomla installation content in the desktop joomla? those are two joomla environments not only one and mobile version is not a page is a directory with a full new joomla installation... now I clarify both installations access to the same db...

Comment: both of the solutions I propose will allow the same functionality, without having two installations: that will keep things simpler; so you'll just delete the installation in /mobile, and create that url in the "main" installation

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way you are doing it is very different from the normal Joomla approach (which would be have a responsive template or have the index.php of the template load different subfiles depending on device), but let's assume you have your reasons.

So you have the same database which means all of the menus are the same, all of the module assignments are the same, all of the template assignments are the same and the default template style is the same.

Now, in Joomla template styles are also stored. This is a json string of pairs with various template options.

Simple case, let's assume that both the mobile and desktop template have the same options.

Now in the templates folder of the mobile site we'll have the mobile template.

Call that mytemplate.

In the desktop site you have a the desktop template.  Call it mytemplate. Install it ONCE.

So these templates have the same name but because they are in two different physical sites they are in two different physical templates folders, one in the mobile site and one in the desktop.

Now we make mytemplate style-1 the default.
In the mobile site this is always going to load the mobile template while in the desktop site it will always load the desktop template.

Now say we assign mytemplate style-2 to the news menu item.  Again the appropriate template is used based on the actual site it is called from.

Now the trickier thing is if you do not have identical parameters. This is likely since the settings you need will be different.   In this case, what you will need to do is make sure that the parameters defined in templateDetails.xml include both sets.  So if you make a new style you need to always set the parameters for both templates.  This is actually going to be helpful since you won't have to configure it twice.

Comment: I didn't do the two installations by myself, another person did that, so I know if I had made that from the begining I didn't make that mistake... XD But I'll try your suggestion, Even I have the same template installed and the two copies in mobile and desktop phisical directories. Sorry about my english...